# Posting a JavaScript Array with jQuery Post to a ASP.NET MVC Action taking a IEnumerable<T>

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

Consider that I have the following javascript that do a post:

```
$.post("/MyController/SomeAction", 
      { myParam: ['Filip', 'Ekberg'] }, function(data) { alert(data); }, "html");
```

My Action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(FormCollection collection, 
                               IEnumerable<string> myParam)
{
    return null;
}
```

When I enter this Action, myParam is null, if I expand the FormCollection I see this:

[image]

The weird part here is that the name ( Key ) is `myParam[]` which might be why it is not mapped to `myParam`.

Also, I tried doing `dynamic[] myParam` as well, but it doesn't work either.

I know that I can use `JSON.stringify` but I don't want to do that now. So, any ideas what's going on here and if there is a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `traditional` parameter to true:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyController/SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { myParam: [ 'Filip', 'Ekberg' ] },
    traditional: true,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Also you can safely remove the `FormCollection` parameter from your POST action signature. It's useless.

Comment: Thanks Darin, worked perfectly. It's a bit weird behaviour though, why isn't the paramemter-binder smart enough to fix that? Anyways, thanks! `FormCollection` was just there to debug it all.

Comment: @FilipEkberg, the default model binder follows strict rules for binding collections: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx The fact that you are not obeying those rules when sending the request is not a reason to blame the model binder for. The thing is that the jQuery team changed the way parameters are serialized in v1.4 and broke compatibility. That's why they introduced the `traditional` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of $.post, you can set `traditional` to true, which should generate the correct name (myParam instead of myParam[]).

The the article about [$.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) for information why.